# How to run a MySQL script using ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a SQL script which I would like to execute from a Java class, running on Windows. I am currently trying to do this using `ProcessBuilder` in the following function:

```
public static boolean runSqlScript(String filename, String user, String password) {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("mysql", "-u"+user, "-p"+password, "< "+ filename);
    try {
        Process pr = pb.start();
        BufferedReader errors = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getErrorStream()));
        BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        while (pr.isAlive()) {
            try {
                System.err.println(errors.readLine());
                System.out.println(output.readLine());
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.err.println(errors.readLine());
        System.out.println(output.readLine());

        int status = pr.exitValue();
        return (status == 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error running command: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

The filename is the absolute path to the script, and the user and password are verified correct. But when I run this, I get the error:

```
ERROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name '< c:/path/to/script.sql'
```

Why is it interpreting that as a database name rather than a command line argument? Can I use ProcessBuilder to run the script like this?

Comment: try to use space character "-u "+user, not "-u"+user...

Comment: No difference, MySQL doesn't care about spaces with the username (just password): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/command-line-options.html "For a short option that takes a value, the option value can immediately follow the option letter, or there can be a space between"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Runtime.exec()` can also be used to send commands, which doesn't seem to have the same issue as `ProcessBuilder`:

```
public static boolean runSqlScriptRuntime(String filename, String user, String password) {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        String cmd = "cmd /c mysql -u " + user + " -p" + password + " < " + filename;
        System.out.println(cmd);
        Process pr = rt.exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader errors = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getErrorStream()));
        BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        while (pr.isAlive()) {
            try {
                System.err.println(errors.readLine());
                System.out.println(output.readLine());
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.err.println(errors.readLine());
        System.out.println(output.readLine());

        int status = pr.exitValue();
        return (status == 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error running command: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

An alternative to trying to simulate command-line arguments is to call the SQL script from inside mysql, as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-batch-commands.html).

```
public static boolean runSqlScript(String filename, String user, String password) {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("mysql", "-u"+user, "-p"+password);
    try {
        Process pr = pb.start();
        BufferedReader errors = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getErrorStream()));
        BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter input = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(pr.getOutputStream()));
        input.write("source " + filename + ";");
        input.flush();
        input.write("quit;");
        input.flush();
        input.close();
        while (pr.isAlive()) {
            try {
                System.err.println(errors.readLine());
                System.out.println(output.readLine());
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.err.println(errors.readLine());
        System.out.println(output.readLine());

        int status = pr.exitValue();
        return (status == 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error running command: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will run MySQL and then call the script. However, I originally was using `ProcessBuilder` because I thought the script could be handled in a single command line - with a solution like this, it probably makes more sense to just use JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add database name and it will work `ProcessBuilder pb = 
    new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "mysql", "-u"+user, "-p"+password,"dbname", " < "+ filename);`

Comment: The real issue is that the command line is interpreting the file as the database name. The script itself is creating a new database and adding tables to it, so I don't initially have or want to use a database. When I use your command (with a different database name that already exists), the process just hangs.

Comment: Script may include create dbname but still u need to add dbname im process builder according  to MySQL command line documentation.So remove the create dbname from script and try to execute as per above answer

Comment: I tried that but the program just hung until I force quit, without running the script or printing anything. (I suspect it may have just run "mysql" and ignored the last arg, not sure how to verify as nothing was printed.) I'm using the script to create so the database can also be set up without needing Java.